# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.resteasy.util.CaseInsensitiveMap.add(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jboss, resteasy

I am new to RestEasy web-service .I am getting the proper response from the restEasy Web-Serivce but when I try to write a web-service client ,I am getting above error.Please find the code as below.
Please let me know where is the issue.
I am using RestEasy 3.0.9 Final.

RestServiceClient.java

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class RestServiceClient {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();
    WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8888/RestSpring/rest/response/hello");
    Response response = target.request().get();
    String value = response.readEntity(String.class);
    System.out.println("Response Value : "+value);
    response.close(); 
   }

}
```

Pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <spring.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <resteasy.version>3.0.9.Final</resteasy.version>
        <jax.rs.version>2.0</jax.rs.version>
        <javax.servlet.version>3.1.0</javax.servlet.version>
        <jackson.version>1.9.4</jackson.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
      <!-- Spring Framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency> 

        <!-- RestEasy  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- RestEasy Spring Integration -->
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId> 
            <artifactId>resteasy-spring</artifactId> 
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- restEasy for file upload -->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.GA</version>
       </dependency>

        <!-- RestEasy Jackson Json Mapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JAX-RS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jax.rs.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Log4j Jar -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Common Lang -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Junit and Mockito -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- RestEasy Client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

RestService.java

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.providers.multipart.MultipartForm;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import com.web.app.rest.object.Employee;
import com.web.app.rest.object.FileUploadForm;

@Controller
@Path("/response")
public class RestService {

    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    public String sayHelloRestEasy(){
        System.out.println("Calling web!");
        return "RestEasy say Hello user!!!";


    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using multipart version 2.2.0.GA, when you are using resteasy 3.0.9 for everything else? NoSuchMethodError is often caused by mixing dependency versions (same with the client, you're using 3.0.2)

Comment: @peeskillet: I have changed the version to latest version , but still getting the error.

Comment: Also get rid of `javax.ws.rs-api`. It will get pulled in

Comment: @peeskillet: Now error is gone but still getting response as error

Comment: What's the error? Please post it?

Comment: @peeskillet: Now getting the response after clearing the project. thanks for your response. As a Solution I removed javax.ws.rs-api and changed the version for mutilpart jar.

Comment: @peeskillet: what is the disadvantage of javax.ws.rs-api ?

Comment: There's no disadvantage. It's used by Resteasy. But Resteasy pulls it in. You should let it do it's work. In this case, it is dependent on 2.0.1. You were using 2.0. My guess is that's where the problem was

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use corresponding version of resteasy-multipart-provider:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
    <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

2.2.0 seems to be very old

Comment: ohh , ok let me change

Answer (score 0):

After change of version and removed javax.ws.rs-api jar getting the response from the servers.
this are the configuration file as below.

pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <spring.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <resteasy.version>3.0.9.Final</resteasy.version>
        <jax.rs.version>2.0</jax.rs.version>
        <javax.servlet.version>3.1.0</javax.servlet.version>
        <jackson.version>1.9.4</jackson.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
      <!-- Spring Framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency> 

        <!-- RestEasy  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- RestEasy Spring Integration -->
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId> 
            <artifactId>resteasy-spring</artifactId> 
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- restEasy for file upload -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
          </dependency>

        <!-- RestEasy Jackson Json Mapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JAX-RS -->
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jax.rs.version}</version>
        </dependency>
         -->
        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Log4j Jar -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Common Lang -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Junit and Mockito -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- RestEasy Client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

web.xml

```
 <listener> 
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class> 
    </listener> 

    <listener> 
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener</listener-class> 
    </listener> 

    <servlet> 
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name> 
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class> 
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/rest</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```